# How to push a comment into a mongoose model of comment which is an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to store comment in an array of comments on post request
My schema is as follows

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")
const bookSchema=mongoose.Schema({
  title:String,
  comments:Array,
  commentcount:Number
})
module.exports=mongoose.model("Book",bookSchema)
```

following is my app.post

```
.post(function(req, res){
      let bookid = req.params.id;
      let comments = req.body.comment;
    
      Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id:bookid},
      {
        $push:{comment:comments}//here i wanna push comment
        },
        {
          $inc:{commentcount:1}//here i wanna increment comment count
        })
        .then(
        data=>res.json(data))
    })
```

in addition to that i wanna increase the comment count on adding each comment.Please help me with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You should push to `comments` field, and you specified `comment`. Just refactor your code like this:

```
.post(function(req, res){
  let bookid = req.params.id;
  let comment = req.body.comment;
    
  Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id:bookid},
    { $push:{comments: comment} },
    { $inc:{commentcount: 1} 
  }).then(data=>res.json(data))
});
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/J0DeY2IB6WF